# How is "stopped short of" understood? What are the parts of speech?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Mr. Hishamuddin, the acting transport minister, said that a statement
>   by a previously unknown group describing the disappearance as the
>   result of a political act didn't appear to be credible. The statement
>   referenced last week's attack by ethnic Uighur separatists in China
>   but ***stopped short of*** an explicit claim of responsibility.
> <sub>Source: [Wall Street Journal — *False Leads Plague Search for Plane*](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702304704504579430210684954006)</sub>

Comment: The last sentence can be read as [The statement referenced X but stopped [short of Y]]. Obviously, *stopped* is a verb. However, though it is obvious that *short of* is a phrase, what its part of speech is is not very obvious. Intuitively, I would say that *short of* is an adjective phrase, being used as a verb complement.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think that's about as good an answer as OP is going to get, assuming this question doesn't get closed as [general reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stop+short+of).

Answer (score 1):

I'd treat *short of* as a compound preposition, like off *off of* or *up over* or *over in*. Alternatively (or in parallel), you could think of *short* as an adverb of location, modified by the preposition phrase headed by *of*.

In either case, *short of an explicit claim of responsibility* is an adverbial of (figurative) location.

> He stopped.
>     Where'd he stop?
>       Short of the finish line.
>       Short of Dallas.
>       Short of an explicit claim of responsibility.

Comment: This question reminds me of the case of *away*, e.g. *The city is miles away*. According to some dictionaries, *away* would be an adverb, but according to some others, *away* would be an adjective.